# How can I disable the Palpatine 'Where've You Been?!' screen?

Tags: star-wars-tiny-death-star

When I launch the Tiny Death Star game, it always shows Palpatine in a chair, saying how much I have made while not playing the game.

[image]

**How can I disable this screen so it immediately shows my Tiny Death Star first?**

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Although you can't disable the screen, you can skip it quickly. The continue button doesn't appear for a second or two, but even before it appears you can tap that spot on the screen to immediately dismiss it.

Comment: COOL! Didn't notice that. Thank you so much!

Comment: This deserves the green checkmark! The other answer doesn't provide a solution (not that I don't like the other answer, this one is just more helpful).

Answer (score 3):

**In my opinion, you can't.**

I know it's annoying and frankly the whole animation is way too long without the option to skip it... But I've been looking all over the game myself and didn't find any disable option.

The game came out like 5 days ago, so we can hope that Nimblebit includes this issue in one of their updates. There's stil a lot of bugs, so I'm expecting an update very soon :-)